# Laravel 5.5 - Issues creating new project

Tags: php, laravel-artisan, laravel-5.5

I'm trying to use **Laravel 5.5**. I updated my php 7.0 to php 7.1. Even, I update my laravel installer package. But, when I try to do:

```
laravel new myProject
```

I get this error:

> You made a reference to a non-existent script @php -r
>   "file_exists('.env') || copy('.env.example', '.env');" You made a
>   reference to a non-existent script @php artisan key:generate
>   Illuminate\Foundation\ComposerScripts::postAutoloadDump You made a
>   reference to a non-existent script @php artisan package:discover

I am using laravel valet and if I go to the browser, when I try myProject.dev is not working. I see this error:

> Whoops, looks like something went wrong.

I tried using:

```
php artisan key:generate
```

inside my project, but I got that:

> [ErrorException]
>   file_get_contents(/Users/jorgeJimenez/Sites/laravel5-5/.env): failed
>   to ope   n stream
>
> : No such file or directory

I noticed, my laravel 5.4 projects are working. I copied a .env file and I put on my laravel 5.5 projects. After that, I run

```
php artisan key:generate
```

and the key was generated and my project in the browser works.
It's supposed, all that process is automatic, but I am not quite sure what is happening.

Answer (score 16, accepted):

You can try update your composer:

`composer self-update`

Comment: After composer self-update, the command laravel new myProject is working fine, again.

Answer (score 0):

I had the same problem. Then I found that there was no problem when i created the first project use laravel 5.5. so I clear composer's cache dir.  It works well now.

Answer (score 0):

This is because of your **Laravel Installer** or **Composer** version. I have faced the same problem and found following *2 different solutions*:

1. Generally you can solve with by running `composer global update` command and then run `composer update` command from your project directory. This solution basically updates your installer and then your project.
2. If still, you have this issue, you need to run `composer self-update` command first and then run `composer update` command from your project directory. Here your composer will update and then your project.

Hope this answer will help you.